# How to block users from editing a node of a content type? (D7)

Tags: 7, users

This should be easy, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong: In my Drupal 7 site, I've defined a content type in the usual way.  I want regular users to be able to **create** instances of that type, but not **edit** them.  Trivial, right?

The content type is in place, and, in admin/people/permissions, there are entries like "My Type: Create new content" and "My Type: Edit own content".  I've set the checkboxes so authenticated users have "create new content" permission but not "edit own content" permission.  Just to be on the safe/superstitious side, I've cleared the cache and done a Rebuild Permissions.  But, nevertheless, my regular users can still edit their nodes.

Shouldn't this work / any ideas what's wrong?  Do I need to write a _node_access handler?

Comment: how edit any content, is it disabled, too ?

Answer (score 0):

Oops: My bad.  I had given authenticated users "bypass node access" permission to deal with a pending bug in the apache_solr module.  Once I dropped this permission, everything worked the way it was supposed to.

Sorry for cluttering up things...